# SQL Connection string on IIS

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, database-connection, iis-8

I am developing a basic ASP.NET MVC CRUD operations web application. I have the solution locally on my Visual Studio connected to my database on the SQL Server that I will be using as production so far all working fine, but when I publish the application I can't connect to my database I can't get to my database.

I really appreciate your help i have looked up online and tried almost every suggested approaches.

- ASP.NET MVC 5 application
- here is my connection string in my solution

  ```
  <add name="DefaultConnection" 
       connectionString="data source=ZUSVS-PBIDW;Integrated Security=True;App=GoTeam;Initial Catalog=GOTeam" 
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  ```

The application works fine in Visual Studio, I am able to connect to the database and perform crud operations.

Here is my LocalSqlServer connection string:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVnaZ.png)

Here is my application connection string on IIS:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yR9JE.png)

Here is the error I am getting:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQGcS.png)

Comment: Seriously, a link to a picture of a connection string?  Make it easy for someone to read and understand your problem by putting everything here  Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V is not a monumental task

Comment: I know you are new but you really need to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read on what constitutes a [MCVE]

Comment: if you can't help me because there is a screen shot of the string instead of the actual string then please do not judge and just move a long and let someone else assist me. I really appreciate your assistance but after 5 hours of work on this, screenshot is what I thought would be the best.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.*

Comment: Visual Studio/IIS uses your credentials to connect to the database, while IIS cannot, https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 So in your case, learn more about SQL Server and IIS, and try to grant the application pool identity enough permissions on the database. Then it can work like breeze.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
I've just spotted the connection string you give in the example doesn't match the value configured in IIS.

Example:

```
data source=ZUSVS-PBIDW;Integrated Security=True;App=GoTeam;Initial Catalog=GOTeam
```

IIS:

```
server=ZUSVS-PBIDW;Database=GoTeam;Integrated Security=true;
```

---

It depends on which SQL server you are connecting to.  Take a look at this link: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Your connection string should probably be something like:

```
Server=ZUSVS-BIDW;Database=GOTeam;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

Comment: Neil, Thank you for your help.